# Chrome fails to download files to some locations

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, download

After updating to Ubuntu 22.04, I can't download files from Chrome to some of the locations in my OS / external drive. However, Firefox works as expected for the same downloads.

What happens? After choosing the target directory and pressing 'Save' - the download doesn't start and 'disappears,' not showing under 'Downloads' in Chrome.

Example. Can successfully download to:

- /home/user/Downloads

Fail to download to:

- /home/user/Downloads/tmp
- /media/user/drive1/folder

I am using the latest Google Chrome version for Ubuntu 22.04.

Is there anything I may tweak?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
```

I solved the problem by installing the above.

Comment: Please [edit] and explain why and how your command fixes the OP's issue. Also please take the [tour] to get a better understanding of how SE/SU works